# How to include JavaScript from a CDN in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I'd like to include JS from a **CDN** in Meteor before including my own client scripts so that the client scripts can depend on it.

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/..."></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/client/..."></script>
...
```

I tried including the script via *.html file and between `<head>` tags. But it seems that header content from *.html files will always be appended to the end of the HTML header, no matter where I place it in the file hierarchy (e.g. placing the file in a lib folder or sorting it alphabetically before client JS files won't help).

Any ideas how I could include JS from a CDN *before* client scripts without having to build a smart package?

Comment: Maybe executing your code *after* the pageload could prevent your code to be dependent on a specific order of loaded js libraries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to load these files before the Meteor packages, create a JS file which is loaded before any of the others. Meteor loads files in alphabetical order so it must be the first file loaded. To that end, naming it `aaLoadCDN.js` should suffice. Dynamically load the CDN scripts by adding a `script src` element to the document `head`:

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');  // optional
script.setAttribute('src', 'url/to/the/cdn/script.js');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Here are some real-world Meteor packages loading scripts from CDNs:

- [snapsvg](https://github.com/mirageglobe/meteorsnapsvgcdn/blob/master/mirageglobe:snapsvgcdn.js)
- [Font-Awesome](https://github.com/nate-strauser/meteor-font-awesome/blob/master/load.js) (CSS).

Comment: One problem with the solution in the blog post linked in this answer is that it doesn't allow you to tell when the script has been executed. As Meteor projects usually will have jQuery available: $.getScript does the job more elegantly.

Comment: What if I need the external javascript file to load first before the meteor packages?

Comment: it says : ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: never, ever, call a file `aa`, that is a very bad practise to be promoting/suggesting

Comment: The entire point of calling it `aa` was to ensure it was loaded first, given that Meteor (at the time of writing) loaded files in alphabetical order. Your edit breaks the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can append the script after the template is rendered. So your script will load only after every other line has been loaded. For example if you directly add a jquery plugin to your template html file, you'll get "jquery not found" error. But this approach prevents that:

```
Template.Main.onRendered(function () {

      $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-formhelpers/2.3.0/js/bootstrap-formhelpers.js"></script>');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also an abandoned package called [meteor-external-fileloader](https://github.com/davidd8/meteor-external-file-loader) that gives an example using Stripe.js. It hasn't been maintained since September 2013, so be careful.