# Deploy Meteor app with CDN links for CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, cdn

I have the following packages added to my Meteor project:

`twbs:bootsrap`
`fortawesome:fontawesome`

When I deploy my application, is there a way to use `settings.json` to swap out the package files to use CDN links instead:

`//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css`
`//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js`
`//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css`

I understand how to include CDN links in my project (like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197398/how-to-include-javascript-from-a-cdn-in-meteor)), but I'm more interested in having the ability to develop locally with the packages and only take advantage of CDN when deployed.

Comment: A clean solution would be to issue a PR for the packages and add a config option to use CDN or local files. Going the `settings.json` route will become horribly intransparent when package updates and settings go out of sync.

Comment: Nice, that makes sense. Then possibly have your `config` for each package read your `settings` for environment to determine local or CDN?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I made a note in case I find some time to do it https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16336

Comment: @Stephan - Awesome, thank you! I hope eventually a working example of that pattern will be submitted here as an answer.